# pre login page using spring securety

Tags: java, spring-security

im using spring boot 3 with spring securety for an web application and want to make a page public, no login requeiert. I´m new to Spring and a bit lost

I sercherd for diffrent things and foud only that the antmatcher wouldt work with path mapping, as well as .permitALL, since u still need to login first

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.